# TWO Silent URL need to setup in the authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net, silent-post

I have two applications which have a different server and using one authorize.net account. I have to put two silent URL in the one authorize.net account. how can i do it ?

Comment: Please add what you have already tried so people can better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one Silent Post URL. In fact, you probably shouldn't be using the same Authorize.Net and merchant account for different sites, but that's on you if you get caught.

You will need to make your Silent Post code smart enough to know which site the payment applies to and then act accordingly. This would probably mean utilizing the description field in the transaction to identify which site it came from. Then your code and use that to determine the originating site and perform whatever actions are necessary.

You also may want to look into [Webhooks](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/webhooks.html) which offers more flexibility than Silent Post although it is more complicated to implement.